# Custom Spring @Profile annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am updating my `@SpringBootApplication` application from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.2 and Spring 4.3 to 5.2 and I am having issues with a custom `@Profile` annotations.

In the older version, I had annotation

```
@Profile("sapConnector")
   public @interface SapConnectorProfile {
}
```

and every bean that belongs to "sapConnector" was annotated with the `@SapConnectorProfile` annotation. When I was running the application I simply defined property `spring.profiles.active=sapConnector` and it loads the beans annotated with this annotation. And if I changed the property to f.e. `spring.profiles.active=demoConnector` it does not load any bean with `@SapConnectorProfile` annotation.

In the new version of Spring, all beans annotated with `@SapConnectorProfile` are loaded even if the property `spring.profiles.active=demoConnector`.

It is not possible to do this anymore in the new Spring?

The profiles work fine if I use annotation `@Profile("sapConnector")` instead of `@SapConnectorProfile`.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Annotation processing has been reworked in 5.2 so this might be a regression. Could you please check with the latest Spring Boot 2.2.1 snapshots as we've fixed something in this area. If that still fails, can you please create an issue with a small sample  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework

Comment: It doesnt work with 2.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT either. Just tried. Good catch Pavel. This is a major bug. Do create an issue as @Stephane mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` annotation.

Everything works fine when I use:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile("sapConnector")
public @interface SapConnectorProfile {
}
```

Issue I have created: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23901

Comment: But `@Profile` already has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` right? Why do we need this explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` on your custom annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile("One")
public @interface FirstMe {

}
```

And dont forget annotate your bean candidate

```
@Component
@FirstMe
public class AMD implements Procesador {
    @Override
    public void tipeArchitecture() {
        System.out.println("AMD Zen 3 [Annotation]");
    }
}
```

Else you'll get `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`

Comment: You are right, but this is nearly the same answer as the accepted one a year before - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58655067/2590615 - you only additionally mention to use the annotation inside the wanted bean (which is IMHO obvious).